# Linked Buttons don't work in responsive tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having an issue with responsive tabs for bootstrap (found here: https://github.com/openam/bootstrap-responsive-tabs) Basically for the most part everything works as it should until it gets down into mobile resolutions at which point the tabs turn into expandable panels. When in this mode the content within gets a little funky but the main issue being that the linked buttons no longer work.

You can click on the buttons and nothing happens at all; whereas in larger resolutions the buttons will take you to google.com

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

The codepen can be viewed here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEovqg

HTML:

```
<div class="container">    

<div class="tabbable tabs-left">

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#option1" data-toggle="tab">Option 1</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#option2" data-toggle="tab">Option 2</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#option3" data-toggle="tab">Option 3</a></li>


</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" >

<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="option1">
<h3>Heading
</h3>
<p>
Something goes here
</p>

<p><b>Key Features:</b>
<br>
blah, blah blah blah</p>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn more</button>
</a>

<!-- /.tab-pane fade -->
</div>


<div class="tab-pane fade" id="option2">
<h3>Heading2</h3>
<p>
Some other stuff here 
</p>
<p>
Hey
</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</button>
</a>

<!-- /.tab-pane fade -->
</div>


<div class="tab-pane fade" id="option3">
<h3>Another Heading</h3>
<p>
Even more content
</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com.com/" target="_blank">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</button>
</a>   

<!-- /.tab-pane fade -->
</div>




<!-- /#myTabContent .tab-content -->  
</div>
<!-- /.tabbable tabs-left --> 
</div>

<!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab_area {
  width: auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* line 797, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* line 803, ../sass/style.scss */
.tab-content > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > .pill-pane {
  display: none;
}

/* line 808, ../sass/style.scss */
.tab-content > .active,
.pill-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

/* line 813, ../sass/style.scss */
.tab-content p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* line 817, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* line 821, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* line 827, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  border-radius: none;
}

/* line 834, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-top-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

/* line 840, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover,
.tabs-below > .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
  border-color: transparent #ddd #ddd #ddd;
}

/* line 846, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}

/* line 851, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  min-width: 74px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/* line 858, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 19px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* line 864, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-right: -1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  z-index: 100;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;*/
}

/* line 874, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #dddddd #eeeeee #eeeeee;
}

/* line 879, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd transparent #ddd transparent;
  *border-right-color: #ffffff;
}

/* line 886, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 19px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* line 892, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-left: -1px;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;*/
}

/* line 899, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
  border-color: #eeeeee #eeeeee #eeeeee #dddddd;
}

/* line 904, ../sass/style.scss */
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover,
.tabs-right > .nav-tabs .active > a:focus {
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  *border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

/* line 912, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
}

/* line 915, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

/* line 919, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading a.collapsed {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* line 922, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading a {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* line 926, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading a:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  content: '\f078';
  float: right;
  -webkit-animation: rotateDownLeft .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: rotateDownLeft .7s both ease;
  animation: rotateDownLeft .7s both ease;
}

/* line 934, ../sass/style.scss */
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  content: '\f054';
  float: right;
  -webkit-animation: rotateUpLeft .7s both ease;
  -moz-animation: rotateUpLeft .7s both ease;
  animation: rotateUpLeft .7s both ease;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#myTab').tabCollapse();
```

Comment: And with linked buttons you mean... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the responsive tabs (the JS), as soon as the window width changes (at least in FireFox), the button-tag gets placed after the a-tag instead of inside it.

But the fast solution should be to change your HTML to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com.com/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">
    Learn More
</a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</button>
</a>
```